# TableView events not being added from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am trying to update values in a tableView value from firebase. The values are being put in the array while in the observe closure, but afterwards, it remains 0, this makes sense because it is asynchronous (correct me if I am wrong). However, this has worked before in previous tableView, so I am not sure what the problem is. This is the code:

```
        let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("createdEvents").observe(.value) { snapshot in
          //self.eventsArray.removeAll()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("createdEvents")
        ref.observe(.value) { snapshot in
            print("start")
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                self.eventsArray.append(rest.key as! String)
            }
               Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(.value) { (data) in
                    let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
                    for(_,value) in events{
                        print(self.eventsArray)
                        if(self.eventsArray.contains(value["EventName"]! as! String)){
                            self.actualEvents.append(AdminEvents(evName: value["EventName"]! as! String, evDesc: value["EventDescription"]! as! String, evStartDate: value["start time"]! as! String, evEndDate: value["end time"] as! String, evNumPeople: value["NumberOfPeople"]! as! Int, evNumRegistered: value["currentPeople"] as! Int))
                           }
                        }
                        print("Actual events array " + "\(self.actualEvents)")
                  }
            }
           self.tblEvents.reloadData()
        }
```

And it prints out the values that I want it to when I tests it. 
[image: the firebase structure]

The end objective here is to go into the users createdEvents and print eventTest and eventTest1 to the tableView, but no values inside there. 
Edit: I forgot to add the events firebase structure, it does exist.
[image]

Comment: what you are trying to append in your array, they are not  in firebase picture you shared.

Comment: Sorry, I added it. However, that array is for storing the events info. I want to actually print the values inside eventsArray, not actualEvents

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any child in your DB with "Events" name.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(.value) { (data) in
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it. For those wondering, I simply just deleted the observe closure around this part, because I realized that the first part was already doing that.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("createdEvents")
    ref.observe(.value) { snapshot in
        print("start")
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            self.eventsArray.append(rest.key as! String)
        }
```

Here is the new code:

```
 Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("createdEvents").observe(.value) { snapshot in
          //self.eventsArray.removeAll()
        print("start")
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            self.eventsArray.append(rest.key as! String)
        }
               Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(.value) { (data) in
                    let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
                    for(_,value) in events{
                        print(self.eventsArray)
                        if(self.eventsArray.contains(value["EventName"]! as! String)){
                            self.actualEvents.append(AdminEvents(evName: value["EventName"]! as! String, evDesc: value["EventDescription"]! as! String, evStartDate: value["start time"]! as! String, evEndDate: value["end time"] as! String, evNumPeople: value["NumberOfPeople"]! as! Int, evNumRegistered: value["currentPeople"] as! Int))
                           }
                        }
                        print("Actual events array " + "\(self.actualEvents)")
                  }
                self.tblEvents.reloadData()
            }
           self.tblEvents.dataSource = self
           self.tblEvents.delegate = self

        }
```